# Find sides of triangle

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I already know two sides $a_2$, $b_2$ and the angle $C$. I don't know angles $A$, $B$ and sides $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$, $c_2$.

How can I find $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$? Or How can I find $c_2$?

Here, $c_2$ is my ultimate goal.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be impossible to find out $c_2$. Consider another line segment parellel to $b_2$, than it will give another value of $c_2$.